# Why does the Smash Bros. announcer say "Rainfall!" in the Wii U character select screen?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Pretty much as per subject. (And if he also does so in previous games or the 3DS version, sorry.) When you select 8-Player Smash, he says, "Eight-player Smash!" but when you pick regular Smash mode, he says what sounds like "Rainfall!"

I thought this might be a muddled way of saying "Ready to fight!" but he says this when the character screen pops up, before everyone is necessarily ready.

Comment: I edited the last bit of your question, as the references to the Japanese accent border on the offensive.

Comment: They don't border on the offensive - they **are** offensive.

Comment: Yes, I see. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Could be a shout out to Operation Rainfall, but no one had to convince Nintendo to bring Super Smash Bros. to North America.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's "free for all". Hope that helps :)